# Outlook rule is not honoring an exception

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules, email-filter

I have an Outlook rule configured for a user so that when they a send a message it will CC two of their staff members.  There is an exception to prevent copying the message if it is sent to a specific user (or group of them, I've tried both).  The message is always copied.  How do I fix this?

Comment: it might help out to copy the image at the end of the rule wizard so we can see whats going on

Comment: Ok, here is the [screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YrRp3w1ApYV1Vra05aNjE5YkE/edit?usp=sharing)